# Angular Universal forward IP from client for all SSR API calls

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I determine the user's city by IP and want the assembled page to refer to a specific city. How can I forward IP to all api requests that SSR makes from the backend? Now there is always 127.0.0.1

```
// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { req });
});
```

what should I change in this code, to have x-ip header on PHP backend then API called from SSR

Comment: You need to pass the IP from your reverse proxy to your nodejs server, then provide that value using DI to the angular app. Then, from the app, send the API along your requests (you do do so using a http interceptor)

Comment: I have IP in node, but cant understand how I can set IP header to all server-side api calls.

Comment: You can add it to the headers in the requests from angular to the API (using an http interceptor if you want to do it all in one place)

Comment: Can you show me examle? (i use default angular universal server.ts)

Comment: Are you using ngPexpressEngine or not?

Comment: app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

yep, default SSR config

Comment: @David , plz help )

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

1. You need to provide angular with the client IP

**server.ts**

```
import { REQUEST } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';

//..
app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) =>
  ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      {
        provide: REQUEST,
        useValue: options.req, //Provides the request to angular
      },
    ],
  })(_, options, callback)
)
```

2. Then, use a [HTTP Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to get the IP adress from the http request and add it to the request sent to the API, e.g. using a custom header like below (or add it a

**injector.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { REQUEST } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';


@Injectable()
export class IPHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) httpRequest: any) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const ip = httpRequest.connection.remoteAddress;

    if(ip) //ip wil be undefined client side
    {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Client-IP: ip
          }
        });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

3. Provide your http interceptor in your app module

**app.module.ts**

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from ‘@angular/common/http’;
//...
 providers: [
 { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: IPHttpInterceptor, multi: true }
```

4. Modify your API to parse to get the IP from the custom header above

Comment: Hi @David i tried this. It still shows the IP of the hosted server

Comment: Log the IP address in server.ts. If it's incorrect, then it's a problem with your reverse proxy setup

Comment: Yeah I tried the logs as well and its always sending me the ip of heroku server which is setup on AWS private ip.

Comment: Well, that's not related to angular then. My solution above is to pass client IP from nodejs server to angular app. If the nodejs server does not have the correct IP, you need to look elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

You need to create or use existing interceptor provided in

**server-state.interceptor.ts**

```
import {Inject, Injectable, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {REQUEST} from "@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens";
import {Request} from "express";

@Injectable()
export class ServerStateInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    let clonedRequest = request.clone({
      headers: request.headers
        .set('X-Forwarded-For', this.request?.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || '')
    });
    return next.handle(clonedRequest);
  }
}
```

Then **app.server.module.ts**

```
providers: [
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ServerStateInterceptor, multi: true},
  ]
```